# awk behaves differently on command-line than from script

Tags: awk

I would expect this to put put '1' but instead it outputs '1 2 3'

```
echo "1 2 3" | awk  "{ print $1 }"
```

However, when running the awk code from a file it does work (where awkscript.awk contains {print $1}):

```
echo "1 2 3" | awk -f awkscript.awk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use:

```
echo "1 2 3" | awk  '{ print $1 }'
```

then it prints `1` from command line also. That is `'` instead of `"` in awk command.

**Explanation:** Using double quote `"` variable `$1` gets expanded beforehand and since that is just an empty string, effectively your command becomes this:

```
echo "1 2 3" | awk '{ print }'
```